# find out radio set`s default checked value on page load with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written a jquery code which simply adds a style to divs.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=radio-set]').change(function() {
            if (this.id == 'first') {
                $("div.second, div.third").removeAttr('style');
                $("div.first").css({"opacity":"1"});
            }
            else if (this.id == 'second') {
                $("div.first, div.third").removeAttr('style');
                $("div.second").css({"opacity":"1"});
            }
            else if (this.id == 'third') {
                $("div.first, div.second").removeAttr('style');
                $("div.third").css({"opacity":"1"});
            }

        });

<input id="first" type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked"/>
<input id="second" type="radio" name="radio-set" />
<input id="third" type="radio" name="radio-set" />

<div class="first">Test Text</div>
<div class="second">Test Text 2</div>
<div class="third">Test Text 3</div>
```

How can I check default checked radio button to add style to its related div on page load?! I added `change()` to the end of jquery code, but as the default checked attribute is on the button with `#first` id, it selected the div with `.third` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this by calling `.trigger('change')` on elements:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=radio-set]').change(function() {
    // lots of code here
}).trigger('change');
```

Don't forget to call your function after DOM is ready.

**EDIT**: sorry, I didn't read your question careful. In your case you should trigger change only on checked radio: `.filter(':checked').trigger('change');`

Comment: I did the same thing, of course by adding simply .change(); but, as I mentioned it selects the wrong div (third) for the button with (#first) id

Answer (score -1):

If you're only wanting the code to run once the DOM is ready, you could do something along the lines of:

```
var selectedInput = $('input[name="radio-set"]:checked').attr('id');
$('div.' + selectedInput).addClass('whatever_style_you_want');
```

Clearly `addClass` could be changed to reflect `css` attributes instead.